# Redirect URL to a Tomcat webapp

Tags: tomcat, rewrite

I have a Tomcat server with two webapps, app1 and app2 (the `app` part is really the same). Each app has an independent group of users.

I would like the groups to be able to access their respective app using `group1.domain.com/app` and `group2.domain.com/app` URLs, meaning that the numbers should be hidden from the URL displayed in browser. I suppose there needs to be a mechanism that would return the correct app based on the `group#` part of the URL.

I have a vague understanding of URL rewrites. Is there a way to do this with only Tomcat? Or do I need Apache HTTP server? I would rather not use Apache if possible, but have no problem going that way if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really about rewriting url but more about virtual hosting.

You can do it in tomcat with the `Host` element in server.xml. For your case, you will want an `Host` `group1.domain.com` where the `appbase` (read folder where tomcat look for war) will contain app1 and an `Host` `group2.domain.com` where the appbase will point to the folder containing app2.

You will maybe need a default Host for those user agent who use the Ip adress.

Thus something like this in server.xml :

```
 <Host name="group1.domain.com" appBase="/war/group1"/>
 <Host name="group2.domain.com" appBase="/war/group2"/>
```

And then app.war in /war/group1 (for the first app) and app.war in /war/group2 (for the second)

see [Tomcat documentation for details](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html)